# How do we implement multivariable in a for loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

```
for(i=0,j=0,k=0; i<x,j<y,k<z; i++,j++,k--) // Assuming x,y,z are already initialised
```

Is there a way to do the same in python in the same line as the loop instead of declaring variables and incrementing inside the loop as

```
i=0
j=0
for k in range (z):
   .
   .
   .
   i += 1
   j += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by creating a generator for each variable and using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to combine them.

`zip` will iterate until the shortest generator is exhausted. As an alternative, see [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
gen_i = range(x)
gen_j = range(y)
gen_k = range(z, -1, -1)  # your example wasn't quite clear, I interpreted it like this

for i, j, k in zip(gen_i, gen_j, gen_k):
    ...
```